# How to find matching items for prefixes in query

Tags: python, string, algorithm, performance, search

I didn't know how to explain it in the question title. Say I have a query of 'Red interest cake' (sorry). I want to search a big database of items (say descriptions). I need to find all descriptions/items that have either this entire query as part of their description or as prefixes. Example:

> Reddish interesting cake

Is eligible because it has 'red', 'interest' and 'cake'.

Is the idea clear? How do I do it? I thought about using a trie but I'm not sure it'd work well.

Comment: Depends on the database and the language, can you edit your question to be more concise?

Comment: Why does it? I want to know the algorithm/approach to use. The language/DB/data structure parts are flexible.

Comment: Split the items by space and check if the words contain the query words

Comment: Do you use SQL language? `red other words interest other words` -> Match?  `red other words interest other words cake` -> Match? `red other words  cake other words interest` -> Match? Is the order important? Is consecutive words important? Is all words should be present? Do you want exact results or ranked relevant results?

Comment: @glegoux 1. If it can be done with SQL then sure, if not then I want to know other approaches. 2. No, they don't match. All words in the query must be present in the item, either as whole words or prefixes or both. 3. The order doesn't matter as long as all words are present.4.  After we get all matching items, we can rank them, but that's a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, finding the query as prefixes means that the query exists as a whole so that way we need only focus on the 2nd part of the question which reduces the algorithm cost.
Here's how I thought about it purely mathematical. Assuming  your database contains about 1 million descriptions and each description say is of length 1000 chars. And your query is of length 100chars( about 10 words avg )
I would suggest retrieving as much of the descriptions as suitable for your machine. then run a kmp string matching algorithm on each record abd if it matches append it into a results dict.
The cost of a kmp algorithm worst case execution when applied would be something like 1 mil *  (10*(1000+100)) operations. which I guess would  take about 10s roughly to get all of ur matches.
not sure if this is an acceptable solution or if my assumptions are accurate. But experimenting with kmp and adding some optimizations for your problem would be definitely interesting.